# How do I get an Azure SendGrid api key?

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I've followed the instructions for [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email) to set up a SendGrid account on Azure. When I use NuGet to get the SendGrid package, it's a much newer version (8.0.5 vs 6.3.4) so the sample for actually sending email is no longer valid.

So, I went over to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) and looked at the Quick Start section to see how the newer api works and I'm stuck--where in the world do I find/get my SendGrid api key?  It's nowhere to be found on my Azure SendGrid account page.

The [SendGrid api keys documentation page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/API_Keys/index.html) has some info on API Keys management, but it makes no sense relative to Azure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to take your username and password from the Azure portal and log in to sendgrid.com itself. From there, you should be taken to app.sendgrid.com. In the left menu, under settings, you can create API keys for your account.

Comment: My API key looks quite different from what the documentation shows. The doc shows something like this, "Authorization: Bearer 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". My key on the other hand looks like just a small subset of this.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar the documentation you're probably looking for is the top half of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email