# How to get Azure SendGrid API Key

Tags: api, azure, sendgrid

I have an Azure with SendGrid pay-as-you-go account. How do I create an API key? Here [How do I get an Azure SendGrid api key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453119/how-do-i-get-an-azure-sendgrid-api-key) it says that in the left menu, under settings, I can create API keys for my account. Except, I have configurations and properties with username and subscriptionId, but no settings option. How do I get the API Key?

Comment: Never mind. I found it.

Comment: You might want to answer your question and mark it as the correct answer.  This will help others.

Comment: Will do. Sorry for my lack of manners.

Comment: No prob.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When viewing your SendGrid account within your Azure account, go to Manage. this will take you to https://app.sendgrid.com/ From there click Settings > Create API Key.

Comment: My API key looks quite different from what the documentation shows. The doc shows something like this, "Authorization: Bearer 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". My key on the other hand looks like just a small subset of this.

Comment: You might be looking at API ID Key. When you create the API, you have to save it because once you navigate to another page, you will not be able to see it again. You have to create a new API key.